# How to add the role "Import Data" to a new user geoserver not Admin

Tags: security, roles, geoserver

I have a geoserver and with my admin user I have the option to "Import Data" (option that allow the user to upload a shp and convert to postgis). I've created a new user without admin roles in order to view only their workspace, but this new user don't have the option "Import Data". I read the documentation, but I could not set this role.

Does anyone know where can I add this role to this new user?.
[image: import data option]

Extra Information: Geoserver - OpenGeo Suite 3.0.2

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, only users with ADMIN role are able to use the "Import Data" option. As example check out the ["Import Data" documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.7.0/user/extensions/importer/using.html):

> Log in as an administrator and navigate to the Data –> Import Data page.

Comment: That is correct, but I want to create a new user only with this option of menu "Import Data". With user ADMIN more options are available by default.

Comment: That's what i'm trying to say :).  Only admins have that option, is not possible (without modifying the code) that a not-admin see the "Import Data" page.

Comment: Well in this case. modify the code is viable, but I could not find the specific file where is the restriction. I found the "importer-2.2-SNAPSHOT" and inside all the class and html files "/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/importer-2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:org/opengeo/data/importer/web/ImportDataPage.html" and .class seems the files that I need to able the permission. I was not lucky at the moment. Anyway thanks Francisco